# Best technique for making edit fields on a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, crud

I am making a simple CRUD interface that when a user selects a certain row from a database that information is grabbed and put inside some fields so they can edit it.

I am wondering if it is a good idea to post the form to itself to propagate the fields or should I do the processing in a different file and have that file send the data back to the original form?

For instance I have a basic Name, Date, and Phone Number fields.  The user can enter their information, it goes into a database and when they submit it shows up on the same page with an edit button.  They hit the edit button and it takes the information from that row and puts it back into the forms so it can be updated.  Is is better to do all processing on one page or split it out and have the data processed in another file and sent back?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any working code or database schema? Does this need to work with several different table to just one? I'd not POST to same form but would incorporate Ajax/JS processor and handle it on the client side. This way user doesn't need to reload the whole page when they choose the row. It also save you a query that populated the grid from which user made the selection. YMMV, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm just in the planning stages now.  I want to make it devoid of JS first so it can work on computers without it and then implement JS after that works to make it easier.  I have seen multiple tutorials of people doing it with a post back to the same form but I am not sure of a solid way of posting to another php page, doing a query, and having that information sent back without making complicated post data back to the main page.  Obviously I am a little new at this so I am just looking for a good starting point and best practices.

Comment: Yes, posting back to the same form *works* but then you need to reload the whole page or frame. If you choose to avoid JS then posting back is perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: Would you say that is a better approach than posting to another php page to get the data and sending it back via $_POST from the query that page performed?

Comment: Well, it depends. I'd go for the cleanest approach you can take. In some cases, it'd be posting to different PHP page while in some other it may be to post back to the same page. Is the 'edit' page similar (e.g. same selection grid) to the page from where you select the line? Based on your question, yes, then it would probably make sense to post back to the same page. If it's completely different editor then you should probably have a separate PHP page. Avoid having the same code on different pages; reuse where possible. Posting back to the same page sounds reasonable.

Comment: Post some snippets of the code you have put together so far and it's easier to comment.

Comment: Ok, I will post some snippets when I get some things worked out with it and it makes more sense.  Thank you so much for your help!